# Ошибка при вызове функции JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const createAlert = (settings) => {

let _createAlertTemplate = (settings) => {
    if(settings === undefined) return false

    const templateAlert = document.createElement('div')
    templateAlert.classList.add('c-alert')
    templateAlert.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
    <div class="l-alert">
        <div class="c-alert__inner">
            <span>${settings.message}</span>
            <svg width="46" height="46" viewBox="0 0 46 46" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            ${settings.statusOk ?  `<path d="M23 46C35.7025 46 46 35.7025 46 23C46 10.2975 35.7025 0 23 0C10.2975 0 0 10.2975 0 23C0 35.7025 10.2975 46 23 46ZM32.4692 9L38.0864 13.1769L21.3481 35.6871L8 24.2459L12.5555 18.9311L20.2075 25.4899L32.4692 9Z" fill="#00C853"/>` : `<path d="M46 23C46 35.7025 35.7025 46 23 46C10.2975 46 0 35.7025 0 23C0 10.2975 10.2975 0 23 0C35.7025 0 46 10.2975 46 23ZM18.0503 23L9.52513 14.4749L14.4749 9.52513L23 18.0503L31.5251 9.52513L36.4749 14.4749L27.9497 23L35.6881 30.7383L30.7383 35.6881L23 27.9497L15.2617 35.6881L10.3119 30.7383L18.0503 23Z" fill="#B71C1C"/>`}
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>`)    
    document.body.appendChild(templateAlert)
    return templateAlert
}

const alert = _createAlertTemplate(settings)
const ANIMATION = 500
let closing = false

return {
    show: () => {
        !closing && alert.classList.add('js-alert_opened')
    },
    hide: () => {
        closing = true
        alert.classList.remove('js-alert_opened')
        alert.classList.add('js-alert_closing')
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert.classList.remove('js-alert_closing')
            closing = false
        }, ANIMATION)
    },
    destroy: () => {
        alert.parentNode.removeChild(alert)
    }
}
```

}

Написал шаблон небольшой всплывашки. Принимает она в себя объект, у которого появились 2 параметра (так необходимо).
Запускаю эту функцию в другой функции и у меня выскакивает ошибка

[image: Ошибочка]

**Здесь запускаю эту функцию**

*Сохраняю в переменную:*
**let alert = createAlert()**

*тут ajax (не покажу его. с ним проблем нет)*

**ВОТ тут запуск**

```
        .done(function() {
            return new Promise(() => {
                createAlert({ // один из запусков (остальные 5 ниже)
                    message: 'Спасибо! Наш менеджер уже набирает Ваш номер, ждите звонка.', // тут достаю поле из объекта параметра функции
                    statusOk: true // второе поле (они кстати работают)
                }).show()
                button.addClass('js-disabled')
            })
            .then(setTimeout(() => {
                alert.hide()
                button.removeClass('js-disabled')
            }, 5000))
            .then(setTimeout(() => {
                alert.destroy()
            }, 5500))
        })
        .fail(function() {
            return new Promise(() => {
                createAlert({
                    message: 'Произошла ошибка! Повторите позже.',
                    statusOk: true
                }).show()
                button.addClass('js-disabled')
            })
            .then(setTimeout(() => {
                alert.hide()
                button.removeClass('js-disabled')
            }, 5000))
            .then(setTimeout(() => {
                alert.destroy()
            }, 5500))
        })
```

[image: ошибочка]

В итоге должно появиться это. (Так оно и делает, но работает неправильно. Без анимации)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. Правильно ли я сделал тут:

```
if(settings === undefined) return false
```

что обозначил этот параметр, как необязательный, потому что не использую при других вызовах?
Спасибо!

Comment: Если `settings === undefined`, то `alert === false`, соответственно `alert.classList.remove('js-alert_opened')` будет равняться `false.classList.remove('js-alert_opened')`. У `false` нету `classList`.

Comment: Тогда как мне указать параметр settings как необязательный? Я собираюсь его использовать не везде

Comment: Смотря, что вы хотите сделать. Что должно происходить, если `settings === undefined` и вызвали `let alert = createAlert(); alert.show()`?

Comment: Если я вызываю `alert.show()`, то тут я хочу использовать `settings` и его поле `message` (определен заранее). НО, у функции `createAlert()` есть еще метод `hide`, и тут мне уже параметр `settings` не нужен. Что тогда тут делать?

Comment: Вы параметр `settings` передаете при вызове `createAlert`. Что должно произойти, если параметр не был передан и вызвано  `alert.show()`?

Comment: Так разве что-то вызовется? `settings` = `undefined`, следовательно выскочит ошибка. А по-хорошему, мне обязательно нужно передавать этот параметр. Потому что он настраивает контент в вызванном окошечке. А теперь, зачем мне настраивать какой-то контент, когда я вызываю функцию закрытия окна. Я решил это другим способом: убрал этот параметр `settings` и добавил новую функцию, которая создает контент в этом окне. В итоге, у меня есть 4 отдельных функции, касательно этого окна: `show()`, `setContent(settings)`, `hide()`, `destroy()`

Comment: У меня нет слов. Я задаю вам вопрос, как автору кода, какое поведение вы хотите получить. А вы мне отвечаете вопросом на вопрос.

Comment: Читайте со второго предложение по четвертое, там описано, почему мне необходимо передавать параметр в одну функцию, но не передавать в другую.

Comment: Вы как будто читаете, но не понимаете вопроса. Я не спрашиваю, ЗАЧЕМ вы хотите передать параметр. Я спрашиваю, что вы ХОТИТЕ получить при вызове `alert.show()`, когда вы не передаете параметр `let alert = createAlert()`. Видите разницу между этими двумя вопросами?

Comment: Я хочу получить алерт поверх документа, в котором есть определенный мною контент.

Comment: Гм, а если вы не **передали параметр settings, как в примере `let alert = createAlert(); alert.show()`**, что вы хотите получить? Ахахах а вообще, вы опять отвечаете на вопрос ЗАЧЕМ))